# Heroku deployed nodejs application has issues with page navigation

Tags: node.js, heroku

```
//This is my server.js node file

var express=require('express')
var path=require('path')
var app=express()
var alfa=express.Router()
var port= (process.env.PORT || 5000)

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/'))
alfa.get('/',function(req,res){

    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'index.html'))
});

alfa.get('/movies',function(req,res){

    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'movies.html'))
})


alfa.get('/shows',function(req,res){

    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'tvshows.html'))
})

app.use('/',alfa)
app.listen(port);
console.log('Go to the port : ' + port);
```

The index.html has a href to movies.html file.

```
<a href="movies">Findout More...</a><span class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right">
```

After deploying to heroku cloud when running the application, the first page loads(without proper css;linked to an external css file, which is expected to be of a similar issue).

On click of the movies href link the error appears in the browser saying internal server error or page not found.

Later I checked the Heroku logs for the application and it says as below:

## /app is appended before the href path movies.html

```
2016-01-30T00:27:06.417098+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/scrol
l.js" host=alfapalakoti.herokuapp.com request_id=6b078679-71a4-436e-9b22-ab87de6
7c534 fwd="50.156.90.248" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=47ms status=200 bytes=6
70
2016-01-30T00:27:06.527645+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/tv.pn
g" host=alfapalakoti.herokuapp.com request_id=05d76121-4af2-4d65-8425-ff4df7684a
6f fwd="50.156.90.248" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=1499
9
2016-01-30T00:27:06.532690+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/timer
.png" host=alfapalakoti.herokuapp.com request_id=5438c650-65e2-4f21-8c10-346f71c
60182 fwd="50.156.90.248" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=2
5665
2016-01-30T00:27:06.540491+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/shows
.jpg" host=alfapalakoti.herokuapp.com request_id=7afbf80b-071d-4ab1-9c18-cb36c71
f444b fwd="50.156.90.248" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=33ms status=200 bytes=3
69678
2016-01-30T00:27:06.625994+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/carou
selbg.jpg" host=alfapalakoti.herokuapp.com request_id=2c371ea0-d47b-46e2-b9a1-51
28fbfaba4a fwd="50.156.90.248" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=112ms status=200 b
ytes=2069053
2016-01-30T00:27:06.781953+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/mainb
g.jpg" host=alfapalakoti.herokuapp.com request_id=e43a6ac3-0b68-40f6-95ba-edc988
a57a91 fwd="50.156.90.248" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=1
1178
2016-01-30T00:27:06.623717+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/movie
s.jpg" host=alfapalakoti.herokuapp.com request_id=61d32aa0-0158-4962-8f8c-5f1a30
2e8654 fwd="50.156.90.248" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=259ms status=200 bytes
=4974518
2016-01-30T00:27:16.482080+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/movie
s" host=alfapalakoti.herokuapp.com request_id=efc2a66c-6ec0-4e76-9afb-39384b8513
52 fwd="50.156.90.248" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=14ms status=404 bytes=208
2016-01-30T00:27:16.492630+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or dire
ctory, stat '**/appmovies.html'**
2016-01-30T00:27:16.492634+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Error (native)
2016-01-30T01:00:47.163686+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2016-01-30T01:00:47.162812+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2016-01-30T01:00:54.049172+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGT
ERM
2016-01-30T01:00:57.704556+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143


//can someone please help me with this?

//why is that being added? How to get rid of it?
```